# FFMPEG Custom Read function reads all the data

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I'm trying to implement a custom read function for ffmpeg that will retrieve a buffer from local video ( from device in the future) and then deocde this buffer, etc..

So, here's my read function

```
int IORead(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size)
{
FileReader* datrec = (FileReader*)opaque;
int ret = datrec->Read(buf, buf_size);
return ret;
}
```

As for the FileReader :

```
class FileReader { 
protected:
  int fd;
public:
  FileReader(const char *filename){ //, int buf_size){
     fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
  };

  ~FileReader() {
      close(fd);
  };

  int Read(uint8_t *buf, int buf_size){
    int len = read(fd, buf, buf_size);
    return len;
  };
};
```

and for the my execution :

```
FileReader *receiver = new FileReader("/sdcard/clip.ts");

AVFormatContext *avFormatContextPtr = NULL;
this->iobuffer = (unsigned char*) av_malloc(4096 + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
avFormatContextPtr = avformat_alloc_context();
avFormatContextPtr->pb = avio_alloc_context(this->iobuffer, 4096, 0, receiver, IORead, NULL, NULL);
avFormatContextPtr->pb->seekable    = 0;

int err = avformat_open_input(&avFormatContextPtr, "", NULL, NULL) ;
if( err != 0)
 {...}
// Decoding process
  {...}
```

However, once the `avformat_open_input()` is called, the read function `IORead` is called and keeps reading the file `clip.ts` until it reaches its end and only then it exit and the decoding process is reached with no data to decode ( as all of it was consumed)

I don't know what is the problem especially that this code

```
AVFormatContext *avFormatContextPtr = NULL;
int err = avformat_open_input(&avFormatContextPtr, "/sdcard/clip.ts", NULL, NULL) ;
```

isn't blocking untill the end of the file is reached.

Am I missing something ?
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, avformat cannot determine the type of your stream. You should use something like

```
avFormatContextPtr->iformat = av_find_input_format("mpegts");
```